# Make a searching box

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to make a searching box, but when I've running the page, no search results will appears. I use of name and family fields for searching. so my code is here:

```
      <fieldset class="fdex" >
            <legend><span class="style4">لیست خدمات انجام شده</span></legend>

            <form name="form1"  dir="rtl" method="post" action="">
<label for="search"> جستجو </label> <br>
<input name="search" type="text" size="40" maxlength="50" placeholder="جستجو کنید"><br />
<input type="radio" name="search_type" value="family" checked="checked">جستجو بر اساس فامیل<br/>
<input type="radio" name="search_type" value="name">جستجو بر اساس نام<br/>
<input type="submit" name="search_user_hasjob" value="جستجو"/>
</form>

            <?php
if(isset($_POST['search_user_job_hasjob']))
{
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_database = 'site';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");

$field = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_type']);
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

// Statement to get all clients that have job and the comments belong to it
$sql_clientName = "
SELECT tablesite.id_user,
          tablesite.name,
          tablesite.family,
          tablesite.phone_number,
          tablesite.email,
          relation.comments
FROM  tablesite
    INNER JOIN relation
    ON tablesite.id_user=relation.user_id
   INNER JOIN job_list
    ON relation.job_id=job_list.job_id
    WHERE $field LIKE '%".$value."%'
GROUP BY tablesite.name;";

// Statement to get specific client job info by User id
$sql_clientJob = "
SELECT job_list.job_name, relation.comments
FROM tablesite
  INNER JOIN relation
    ON tablesite.id_user=relation.user_id
  INNER JOIN job_list
    ON relation.job_id=job_list.job_id
WHERE $field LIKE '%".$value."%' AND id_user = ?;";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_clientName);
$stmt->execute();
$output = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();

// Go through all clients and print them out
echo "
<table width='900px'>
<tr>
    <td>نام</td><td>نام خانوادگی</td><td>تلفن</td><td>مشاغل</td>
</tr>
";

while ($row = $output->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['family'] . "</td><td>" . $row['phone_number'] . "</td>
    ";

    // We call statement once
    $stmt1 = $conn->prepare($sql_clientJob);
    $stmt1->bind_param("i", $row['id_user']);
    $stmt1->execute();
    $output1 = $stmt1->get_result();

    // Fetch the job name belong to the client
    echo "<td>";
    while ($row1 = $output1->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        echo $row1['job_name'] . ", ";
    }
    echo "</td>";

    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
$stmt1->close();
}
?>

</fieldset>
```

So when I'm trying to get information, page give me null. thanks for your help.

Comment: What would I suggest is to check DB collation type(I suppose your queries in Arabic so it should be either utf8_general_ci or utf8mb4_general_ci) and DB Engine(should be InnoDB). Also please post `var_dump($_POST);` output while running your request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your submit button name and in your `$_POST` has different name:

```
<input type="submit" name="search_user_hasjob" value="جستجو"/>
```

**$_POST** has not the same submit button name:

```
if (isset($_POST['search_user_job_hasjob']))
```

This mean your condition does never accept the form submitting and won't return any search results, try to correct it so both has same name like

```
if (isset($_POST['search_user_hasjob']))
```

It should work

---

**Addition**
Regarding problem in comments from OP with `Fatal error: Call to a member function close()`.

This is because you have `$stmt1->close();` out of while loop curly braces `{ }`, what you need to do is to move the `$stmt1->close();` inside while loop like this:

```
....
$output1 = $stmt1->get_result();
$stmt1->close();
....etc
```

This should help with out digging deep in code analysis.

Comment: hey Maytham you are here, I'm glad :) there is another more problem, when i insert a name or family that not exit, i see this error: Notice: Undefined variable: stmt1 in C:\wamp\www\source\users_has_job.php on line 270 and this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function close() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\source\users_has_job.php on line 270. i seems i need to remove line $stmt1->close(); yes?

Comment: Sure I am always in SO but right now I am out,  will look at it soon I am back again